# Array of values from and array of arrays without loops

Tags: php, arrays, filtering

Let's say I have a data set in PHP that is in the form of:

```
$array = [{"prior":"0","id":"61039","type":"todo"},
{"prior":"1","id":"70341","type":"todo"},
{"prior":"3","id":"39104","type":"todo"},
{"prior":"4","id":"70315","type":"todo"},
{"prior":"6","id":"72050","type":"todo"},
{"prior":"7","id":"72329","type":"todo"},
{"prior":"8","id":"73992","type":"todo"}]
```

I want to process this array of arrays so that I have a single array with integer indexes and the values of only id.
It's trivial to simple use loops:

```
$data = array();
foreach($array as $item){
    $data[] = $item['id'];
}
```

What I want to know, is there a way to do this, disregarding efficiency, using the built in array functions of PHP (with no loops), or am I stuck using the foreach loop?

Comment: You can use functions that use closures, however they are effectively still loops.

Comment: Warning: the javascript-like notation is valid! Do not edit the question to change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can  use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) for this:

```
$data = array_map(function ($el) { return $el['id']; }, $array);
```

Note that this still has to perform the looping internally; it's just not shown explicitly as in a `foreach` loop. This approach will be far less efficient than a plain 'ol `foreach`.

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/190817)

Comment: One line, perfect haha!

Comment: @TheBat: Glad to have helped. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 2):

With PHP >= 5.5.0:

```
$array = json_decode($array, true);
$ids   = array_column($array, 'id');
```

Comment: For <= PHP 5.5.0, you can use this wrapper function: https://github.com/ramsey/array_column (written by the same author who wrote the original `array_column()` for PHP).